# Show means with points and horizontal lines (segments) with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot data of three groups. Specifically, I want to show individual data points including the means of the three groups. Here's what I have so far:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(group=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=10), value=rnorm(30))

ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(x=group, y=value)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_summary(fun="mean", geom="point", color="red", size=5) +
    stat_summary(fun="mean", geom="segment", mapping=aes(xend=..x.. + 0.25, yend=..y..))
```

This produces the following figure:

[image: This is what I have]

However, I would like the horizontal line segments to start to the left of each group's mean instead of starting at the center. I tried specifying `mapping=aes(x=..x.. - 0.25, xend=..x.. + 0.25, yend=..y..)`, but this just gives me an error:

```
Error: stat_summary requires the following missing aesthetics: x
```

I don't understand why I can't use `..x..` to specify the `x` aesthetic, whereas it works for the `xend` one.

Any idea how I can make the horizontal line segments symmetric around the group centers?

Comment: What about `mapping=aes(xend=..x.. - 0.25, yend=..y..)`?

Comment: This draws the segments on the other (left) sides. Do you mean I need to do this in two steps (i.e. add two separate layers)?

Comment: Yeah, it might be a solution!

Comment: Indeed, this works! It seems a bit clunky and I still don't know why I can't use `..x..` with the `x` aesthetic, but at least it works. Do you want to write that into an answer?

Comment: On that now, please check and accept if you wish :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (Maybe not the most elegant solution):

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(group=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=10), value=rnorm(30))

ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(x=group, y=value)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(fun="mean", geom="point", color="red", size=5) +
  stat_summary(fun="mean", geom="segment", mapping=aes(xend=..x.. - 0.25, yend=..y..))+
  stat_summary(fun="mean", geom="segment", mapping=aes(xend=..x.. + 0.25, yend=..y..))
```

[image: e chec]

Comment: @cbrnr Fantastic! I hope this helped with your issue :)

Comment: I have another problem: what do I do if I want to have a log-scale on the y-axis, i.e. add the following to your solution: `+ scale_y_log10()`?

Comment: @cbrnr or you can set `scale_y_continuous(trans='log10')`

Comment: This doesn't work. One problem are negative numbers - I replaced them with `runif(30)` in the example. However, it still doesn't work - the horizontal segments are not drawn and I get a buch of warnings (NaNs produced).

Comment: @cbrnr Yeah because of zero values, I believe you can try with `scale_y_log10()` and playing with it after `geom_point()` or after stats summaries!

Comment: Hm. It doesn't matter where i put `scale_y_log10()`. And I don't have negative values anymore, that's why I don't understand why it's not working. I could open a new question though if this requires substantial changes.

Comment: @cbrnr So you want to keep all equal and just change the scale on y to log10 right?

Comment: @cbrnr Try geom_blank() for the scale and then you could use the rest of the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218544/discussion-between-cbrnr-and-duck).

Answer (score 2):

This comes up pretty high on the search and, although I think it's a clever approach, I think the way to have the summary as requested is using `crossbar` for the `geom`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(group=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=10), value=rnorm(30))

ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(x=group, y=value)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", color="red", size=5) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="crossbar")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>